# How to convert Excel VBA created on a mac to Windows?

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a VBA for a button in Excel for Mac that is supposed to copy the content of a few selected cells on one tab and paste it (as values) on the first available cell in an assigned row on a different tab.

This is the first time I've ever had a go at making this, so I probably didn't do it as efficient as possible, but it works.

The problem is that it only works on Mac. My co-workers that I've made it for uses PC. Can I convert the code to work on Excel for PC?

**Edit:** I should have been more explicit into what the problem actually is (thanks @KenWhite).

So here's what happened:

1. I created the file and the VBA.
2. I saved my file and attatched it to an email
3. my co-worker saved it and opened it up
4. When she pressed the button she got an **error** "*Indexet är utanför intervall*". My best translation for this is **Index out of Range** (but I'm not completely sure)

I suspected that it had to do with Mac -> PC, but some have pointed out that there should be no difference. I realize that the named on the sheets and that the data needs to be in the exact same spot - but that shouldn't be an issue in this case.

**Edit 2:** It seems to be a problem with special characters. the "ä" and "ö" used in the sheet names where changed in to "š" and "¨" in the VBA code on their end. I can't test it right now, but my guess is that the code will work if I either manually change the characters in the code or make sure to use sheet names without special characters.

If I should/could add additional information, let me know and I'll make another edit.

Thank you everyone.

```
Sub Generera()
'
' Generera Makro
'

'
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    BMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & BMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    CMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C" & CMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    DMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D" & DMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    EMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E" & EMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    FMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F" & FMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    GMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G" & GMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    HMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("H" & HMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    IMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("I" & IMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("veckoräckvidd").Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
    JMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("J" & JMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really see anything specific to macs here. I'll be that there's a difference in their workbooks that is preventing this from working for them

Comment: Thanks! What would you guess the difference could be when they open my file on their machines? How can I circumvent that?

Comment: There is no difference. What **specific problem** are you having? What problem are they having when they open the file? Instead of asking us to speculate on anything that might go wrong, [edit] your post and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve. You say *the problem is*, but never actually identify a problem. This site is for **specific questions** about **actual problems**, not *guess what might be happening and how to fix it*.

Comment: The main things you have to be careful of with macros like this is that all sheets are named the same and that all data is in the *exact* same place on both sheets in yours and their excel files

Comment: Where exactly does the error happen? One cause could think of is that the code tries to select a cell at column/row position ´0´ which does not exist. On the other hand, @Marcucciboy2 code is probably the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, Index out of range for your code can really only be about the worksheet names

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a replacement for your current macro, so this might solve your problem.

```
Sub Generera()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = sheets("Utveckling över tid")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = sheets("veckoräckvidd")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 10
        Dim colLetter As String
        colLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)

        ws1.Range(colLetter & ws1.Cells(rows.count, colLetter).End(xlUp).row + 1).value = ws2.Range("B" & i - 1).value
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

Here are the steps I took to convert your original code to my shorter version:

```
Range("B1").Select
Selection.copy
sheets("Utveckling över tid").Select
BMaxRows = Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
Range("B" & BMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

---

[Stopped using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and started using direct `Range().value` transferring instead of `.copy` and `.pastespecial` so that I dont have to juggle `cutcopymode` and because you're not doing anything special, just copying the values only.

```
BMaxRows = sheets("veckoräckvidd").Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
sheets("veckoräckvidd").Range("B" & BMaxRows + 1).value = _
    sheets("Utveckling över tid").Range("B1").value
```

---

Include the statement for `BMaxRows` inside of the range itself for eventual simplicity.

```
sheets("veckoräckvidd").Range("B" & sheets("veckoräckvidd").Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1).value = _
    sheets("Utveckling över tid").Range("B1").value
```

---

Use `Worksheet` variables to shorten every time that I need to refer to one of the sheet names.

```
ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1).value = _
    ws1.Range("B1").value
```

---

And to convert it to a loop you can compare a couple of the converted operations side by side to see what changes every instance. In this case it's the column letter for `ws2` and the row number in `ws1`.

```
ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1).value = ws1.Range("B1").value
ws2.Range("C" & ws2.Cells(rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row + 1).value = ws1.Range("B2").value
ws2.Range("D" & ws2.Cells(rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1).value = ws1.Range("B3").value
```

Comment: Wow. Awesome! Thank you! This looks a lot more efficient! And actually taught me a lot of how VBA's work.